# Pushing mov or lea to stack

Tags: assembly, x86

I have two lines of code.

```
leal   12(%ebp), %ecx
pushl   %ecx
call    func
```

and

```
movl   12(%ebp), %edx
leal    (%edx), %ecx
pushl   %ecx
call    func
```

Where I have a C-function `func(&argument)`. The first line works, and the other doesn't. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: `leal (%edx), %ecx` is equivalent to `movl %edx, %ecx` and so your second code is equivalent to `push 12(%ebp)` that is it pushes the value not the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `lea` is a shift-and-add instruction, but `mov` (with a memory source operand) is a load, so the 2nd block does `func(argument)`.  Obviously this doesn't work when `func(&argument)` is correct.

The insn reference manual (links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki) documents what instructions do.

Comment: But all I do is move a value to a new address, and push the loaded effective address of the new addres to the stack. Why is this not the same? In both cases I use `lea` on a value in an address, and push it to stack.

Comment: @Andreas: Single-step in a debugger and look closely at the values in registers.  `lea   (%edx), %ecx` doesn't undo the load, it treats the value you loaded as a pointer.